# Is there any data set for querying labor certification data?

Tags: labor

Is there any dataset for querying data available in the Labor Certification registry (https://icert.doleta.gov/index.cfm?event=ehLCJRExternal.dspQuickCertSearch)

Comment: Can you explain what you are looking for? Do you want to access the data via API? Know if there is raw data dump in CSV or XML format? By clarifying your question you will increase your chance to have a quality answer.

Comment: They do not seem to have a bulk data download (shame) but if you use your browser's dev tools you can see the URL the form submits to and it looks like you can get up to 1000 results at a time even though the web UI wont show it to you.

Comment: They provide quarterly data in excel format [https://www.foreignlaborcert.doleta.gov/docs/py2015q4/PERM_Disclosure_Data_FY15_Q4.xlsx](https://www.foreignlaborcert.doleta.gov/docs/py2015q4/PERM_Disclosure_Data_FY15_Q4.xlsx). I am looking for any API to get the same information on a daily basis. The URL for the browser's form has only limited columns.

Comment: Sometimes you need to contact the organization and ask -- if they don't think that anyone would be using the data in a given way, they wouldn't bother making it available.  If you explain your need, they might start offering daily dumps.

Comment: Did you ever get around finding an answer regarding iCERT data access?